# How do you send a text response using the Python client for Dialogflow v2?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I was following [this tutorial](https://chatbotslife.com/for-beginners-deploying-your-own-ai-nlp-bot-on-fb-messenger-39410a0dc127) that demonstrated how to create and deploy a chatbot using the v1 version of the Dialogflow API.

I am trying to follow along using Dialogflow V2, but I am struggling with even the most basic of tasks, such as sending messages.

So, how do I send a message from the Python client for Dialogflow V2?

Comment: have you enabled V1 or V2 in Dialogflow? show your settings and update the question.

Comment: It would seem self evident that I have activated V2.

Comment: when you are asking question on SO, nothing is self evident. sometimes people make most basic mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably not try to learn Dialogflow with the old ApiAi libraries and v1 of the webhook, as they are very outdated and most materials, including most of the Dialogflow docs, apply only to the v2/v2beta1 versions.

That said, all you are really going to do is to answer [this](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#request) JSON POST body with a JSON like [this](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response). Dialogflow does not have a Python fulfillment library, but you may get a long way with Flask or a third party library like [Flask-Assistant](http://flask-assistant.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: To add to this, the example there for the response JSON is more complicated than it needs to be. Mine only has two fields: outputContexts list (which I leave empty, they seem to update themselves anyway) and string fulfillmentText.